# Unable to shift text upwards in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm probably really sleepy and missing something easy here. I've tried every margin and padding available but I'm unable to *lift* a `span` (`div` or any other text containing element for that matter) that contains some text to the right level.

What's the best way to achieve this? In the fiddle below, i want to align it with the font-awesome icon.

```css
.add-cohorts-button > a > i {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.add-cohorts-button > span {
    padding-left: 8px;
    /*any amount of bottom margin/padding doesn't work. Try it. Height didn't either */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-xs-3 add-cohorts-button">
  <a href="addcohort.form"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>Hello from the other side </span></a>
</div>
```

Way out of this fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Suits you?

Adjust the margin according to your icon height.

```css
.add-cohorts-button > a > i {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.add-cohorts-button span {
      position:absolute;
      padding-left:8px;
      margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-xs-3 add-cohorts-button">
  <a href="addcohort.form"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>Hello from the other side </span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked fine. Thanks! Might want to delete your older answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` on your link so that it can fit its height to its contents, then use `vertical-align: middle`, like this:

```css
.add-cohorts-button a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.add-cohorts-button > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-xs-3 add-cohorts-button">
  <a href="addcohort.form"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <span>Hello from the other side </span>
</div>
```

Version with the whole thing as a link:

```css
.add-cohorts-button {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.add-cohorts-button i {
  display: inline-block;
}

.add-cohorts-button > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a class="col-xs-3 add-cohorts-button" href="addcohort.form">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>Hello from the other side </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response. It is actually the entire thing (icon + text) I want to link. I have changed the code accordingly

Comment: @bholagabbar Added a new version to my answer.